# ¿Cómo puedo acceder a un vector que está creado a través de una variable struct que, a su vez, usa otra variable struct?

Tags: c++, array, struct, estructuras, vectores

Estoy haciendo el código para un proyecto y necesito usar un vector de una variable que a su vez usa otra variable, ambas las defino con un struct:

```
struct uno {

    char ej, ej2;

};

struct dos {

    uno x;
    vector <int> y;
    char k;


};
```

Estas son las variables que he definido. El problema surge cuando hago el programa, el cual me complia bien pero después no me funciona. Este es un main que he hecho de ejemplo:

```
int main () {
    int i=0
    vector <dos> hola;
    hola[i].x.ej = 'd' ;
    
cout << hola[i].x.ej << endl;

}
```

Espero haberme explicado, he estado buscando por todas partes y no encuentro la manera de que me funcione el programa que estoy haciendo.

Comment: ¿ Que problema **exacto** es el que estás obteniendo ? ¿ De compilación, de ejecución ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu vector está vacío, por lo tanto no puedes acceder `hola[i].x.ej`, esto lo puedes comprobar haciendo:

```
cout<<"Tamaño:"<<hola.size()<<endl;
```

Necesitas primero llenarlo de valores, como por ejemplo, así:

```
struct uno {
    char ej, ej2;
};

struct dos {
    uno x;
    char k;
};


int main () {
    int i=0;
    std::vector<dos> hola;
    
    //Crea instancias de estructuras, ya inicializadas
    uno test1 = {'c','a'};
    dos test2 = {test1, 'x'};
    
    //Añadela al vector
    hola.push_back(test2);
    
    hola[i].x.ej = 'd' ;
    
    std::cout << hola[i].x.ej << std::endl;

}
```